# How to Install Apache on Amazon EC2 (AMI) without using yum command

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, redhat, amazon-ami

Hi We are trying to Install Apache on Amazon EC2 (AMI) without using yum package manager. We want to Install it in way like we will download the Apache setup, then compile it and then unpack it. We are not able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Which version and flavour of Linux are you using? Did you check if Apache is already installed and running? What is the error you are getting?

Please see if the steps mentioned in the below link is of any help.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287406/install-apache-and-php-on-centos-without-package-manager-yum-rpm

Comment: Thanks Nans. I was trying to install the amazon redhat.